# Is there a Kotlin equivalent for Swift's @discardableResult annotation

Tags: android, swift, kotlin

I am working on an Android-native project with Kotlin. I want to add a behaviour to my helper Class in which I want its result, discarded in some cases.

In Swift, I was able to do that with `@discardableResult`,

```
@discardableResult
func checkForStatus() -> Bool {
   ...
}
```

I want to achieve the same behaviour on the Android-Kotlin end, Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: See also: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12719

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as i known there is no annotation for this because we don't need it. This behavior is default in kotlin, Android Studio is not making any warnings about not using function return value. We actually have to annotate functions which return value matters.

To make check for using returned value we are using `androidx.annotation.CheckResult` annotation. Now IDE will check if you are using returned value from function.

**Simple example**

```kotlin
fun getTrue(): Boolean = true

@CheckResult
fun getFalse(): Boolean = false

fun main() {
    //No warning, it's up to you to use returned value or not
    getTrue()
    
    //Warning, indicates returned value should be used to something
    getFalse()
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!, @CheckResult annotation will do the job for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Kotlin several years, AFAIK Kotlin doesn't produce warnings for unused return values, so you don't need an explicit annotation like in Swift. Just calling the function without using its return value achieves the desired behavior of discarding the result.